# How can I fix this error that I am getting with my pthread code?

Tags: c, macos, terminal, pthreads, mutex

I'm currently a beginner learning how to use pthreads in C. My code currently runs so there are no actual bugs but it doesn't so what its supposed to do. The code should prompt the user for each question and then print all the results once the user has entered their information but the code seems to skip and finish once the name has been inputted. Please can someone help me find where I'm going wrong on my code?  Below is my code and the output when its been run:

```
#include <stdio.h
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <sched.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>

pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

typedef struct compound {
     char name [1024];
     int age;
     int birthMonth;
     int birthYear;
     int threadNumber;
}compound;

   void * threadName (void * param){

    compound *lparam = (compound *) param;

    int lock;

    lock = pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

    printf ("> Please type your name for thread %d\n", lparam->threadNumber);
    scanf ("%c", lparam->name);

    lock = pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

    lock = pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

    printf ("> Please type your age for thread %d\n", lparam->threadNumber);
    scanf ("%d", &(lparam->age));

    lock = pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

    lock = pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

    printf ("> Please type your birth month for thread %d\n", lparam->threadNumber);
    scanf ("%d", &(lparam->birthMonth));

    lock = pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

    lock = pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

    printf ("> Please type your birth year for thread %d\n", lparam->threadNumber);
    scanf ("%d", &(lparam->birthYear));

    lock = pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    return NULL;
}

// main function
int main ( void) {

    pthread_t thread_ID3, thread_ID4;
    void *exitstatus;

    compound first, second;
    first.threadNumber= 1;
    second.threadNumber = 2;

    pthread_create (&thread_ID3, NULL, threadName, &first);
    pthread_create (&thread_ID4, NULL, threadName, &second);

    pthread_join (thread_ID3, &exitstatus);
    pthread_join (thread_ID4, &exitstatus);

    printf("Finished\n");

    getchar();
    return 0;
}

This is what happens when the code is executed:

[370user14@nostromo ex2]$ make
gcc -Wall  -c base_code.c
gcc -lm -lpthread base_code.o  -o baseprog
rm -f *.o *~
[370user14@nostromo ex2]$ ./baseprog 
> Please type your name for thread 1
gurinder
> Please type your age for thread 1
> Please type your birth month for thread 1
> Please type your name for thread 2
> Please type your age for thread 2
> Please type your birth month for thread 2
> Please type your birth year for thread 2
> Please type your birth year for thread 1
Finished
```

Comment: "My code currently runs so there are no actual bugs but it doesn't so what its supposed to do." Most games run anyway if they have bugs. A bug is semantic misbehavior, which very well allows the code to compile.

Comment: You might want to learn sequential programming before trying multithreaded programming. Your use of `scanf()` is disturbing.

Comment: You might want to check the first call to [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf), that doesn't seem line the right format to read a string...

Comment: "My code currently runs so there are no actual bugs but it doesn't so what its supposed to do" - that's what the romans mean with "contradictio per se".

Comment: 1) the posted code contains this line: `#include <stdio.h` which is missing the final `>`      2) the posted code sets variable `lock` but never uses it.

Comment: when calling the system function: `scanf()`, always check the returned value (not the parameter value) if the returned value does not match the number of format specifiers, then an error occurred (note: do not count format specifiers that say to ignore the input.)

Comment: regarding this line: `scanf ("%c", lparam->name);`.   1) heed my prior comment regarding `scanf()`.  2) the `lparam->name is declared to be 1024 characters.  however the format specifier is only consuming 1 char `%c`  suggest: `scanf ("%1023s", lparam->name);`  Notice that the max char count is 1 less than the length of the `name` field to allow for the NUL byte that `scanf()` always appends to a field that was input via the `%s` format specifier

Comment: a thread should be exited via `pthread_exit( status );` (or, in this case: `pthread_exit( NULL );` )

Comment: the final call to `getchar()` will not stop.  It will input the newline left over from the last call to `scanf()`.   Suggest: `int ch; while( (ch = getchar()) !=EOF && '\n' != ch );  getchar();`

Comment: 1) it is a bad programming practice to #include header files that are not actually used.  2) please follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: there is no need to save a return value if it is not going to be checked.  so the `lock` variable can be eliminated.  Similar statements apply to the `exitstatus` variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the corrected code, with the call to scanf() fixed, the clutter removed, appropriate error checking included, the axiom *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement* followed and the other comments incorporated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> // exit(), EXIT_FAILURE
#include <pthread.h> // pthread_*()
//#include <semaphore.h>
//#include <sched.h>
//#include <unistd.h>
//#include <signal.h>
//#include <sys/types.h>
//#include <string.h>


pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

typedef struct compound
{
     char name [1024];
     int age;
     int birthMonth;
     int birthYear;
     int threadNumber;
} compound;


void * threadName (void * param)
{
    compound *lparam = (compound *) param;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

    printf ("> Please type your name for thread %d\n", lparam->threadNumber);
    scanf ("%1023s", lparam->name);

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

    printf ("> Please type your age for thread %d\n", lparam->threadNumber);
    scanf ("%d", &(lparam->age));

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

    printf ("> Please type the number of your birth month for thread %d (January=1)\n", lparam->threadNumber);
    scanf ("%d", &(lparam->birthMonth));

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

    printf ("> Please type your birth year for thread %d\n", lparam->threadNumber);
    scanf ("%d", &(lparam->birthYear));

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    pthread_exit( NULL );
} // end function: threadName


// main function
int main (void)
{

    pthread_t thread_ID3;
    pthread_t thread_ID4;


    compound first;
    compound second;

    first.threadNumber= 1;
    second.threadNumber = 2;

    if( 0 != pthread_create (&thread_ID3, NULL, threadName, (void*)&first) )
    { // then pthread_create failed
        perror( "pthread_create for first thread failed");
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else pthread_create successful

    if( 0 != pthread_create (&thread_ID4, NULL, threadName, (void*)&second) )
    { // then pthread_create failed
        perror( "pthread_create for second thread failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else pthread_create successful

    pthread_join (thread_ID3, NULL);
    pthread_join (thread_ID4, NULL);

    printf("Finished\n");

    int ch;
    while( (ch = getchar()) != EOF && '\n' != ch );
    getchar(); // wait for user to enter a final keystroke
    return 0;
} // end function: main
```